# CDF of sum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are $dependent$ random variables, what would be the cumulative distribution of $X+Y$?

That is, what is $P(X+Y\le c)$ for any integer c?

Note that we do not know their joint distribution

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on the *joint* distribution of $X$ and $Y$. 
For any $\alpha$, not necessarily an integer, we have that for 
discrete random variables, 
$$P\{X+Y\leq \alpha\} 
= \sum \sum P\{X = u_i, Y = v_j\} = \sum \sum p_{X,Y}(u_i,v_j)$$ 
where the double sum is over all $i$ and $j$ such that $u_i + v_j \leq \alpha$. For jointly continuous random variables, we have
$$P\{X+Y\leq \alpha\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{v=-\infty}^{v=\alpha - u}f_{X,Y}(u, v)\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: thanks I should have mentioned that we do not know their joint distribution.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @May If you do not know the joint distribution, then the problem is not solvable. It _might_ be possible to obtain some _bounds_ in some cases.

Comment: The solution Dilip provided can also be expressed in terms of the conditional probability, which is sometimes attainable in terms of the problem. Of course, if you have this, you can likely find the joint distribution... But the intermediate step is convenient in some cases.